# How flutter works behind the scenes?

Tags: flutter

I have preferred flutter as my primary app development platform,but I don't know how does it work behind the scenes.Will my dart code going to be converted into Java code and get executed then?

I have tried searching many YouTube videos but none of it worked for me,as they were just explaining only about dart but not about java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Flutter convert Dart code into Java/Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818897/does-flutter-convert-dart-code-into-java-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter works by using the Dart programming language to create app logic and user interfaces. Your Dart code is compiled into optimized machine code that directly interacts with the Flutter engine. This engine shows your app's tools and handles interactions on platforms like iOS, Android, and the web. You don't have to change Dart to Java or Swift; Flutter's engine takes care of running and displaying the code.

So, to answer your question, Dart code is not turned into Java code and then run. Instead, Dart code is turned into optimized machine code that talks directly to the Flutter engine. The Flutter engine takes care of displaying and interacting with the hardware and native features of the device.

Answer (score -1):

Take my answer with a grain of salt, since I have been following **Flutter** development for a while, but I am far from being knowledgeable on how the core actually works since I haven't dug deep into it yet.

However, there are some things that can tip you off on how it actually works.

When you build an app, and run it into the browser, you will notice that there is not a single Text element, or CSS style, and even the Javascript produced, is mostly generated with a single purpose. To display a **HTML Canvas on the screen**.

The first time I saw this, I immediately realized that this is the reason Flutter is able to run on such different devices.13 years ago, when I started learning how Canvas works, I had a pretty similar idea for a multiplatform  project.

**HTML5 Canvas** is one of the most consistent technologies we have across different systems, and platforms since there is a global effort to make it standard.

Obviously, **Android**, **Windows**, **iOS**, and **Linux**, have specific platform implementations, sometimes use different programming languages, and have specifics like the handling permissions, that are necessary to create Apps for their own devices.
Each one has its own setup for the app's main view, but I bet that most (visual) work is basically done with **HTML5 Canvas and Javascript**.

This is what obviously creates some **performance limitations** on these apps.
Luckily nowadays we are able to run accelerated apps, through the browser, because **GPU-accelerated Web apps** are now possible, and it's predicted that pretty soon we can even run **WebAssembly** on most devices, and this can revolutionize Flutter app performance.